# cannot import moveit_commander

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-commander

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i tried to run this code

```
import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
```

and got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthonio/kuka_bot/src/agilus/src/testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    import moveit_commander
  File "/home/anthonio/moveit/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/anthonio/moveit/src/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/planning_scene_interface.py", line 48, in <module>
    import pyassimp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyassimp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>


    from .core import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyassimp/core.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import structs
```

can someone please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241108/cannot-import-moveit_commander/) by [nio4990](https://answers.ros.org/users/27541/nio4990/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The errors in your question look like a python2 / python3 compatibility issue. Though you did not copy and paste the actual error, only the traceback so it's hard to know for sure. [releated debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0